# different admin panel for different website Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have two files in Magento index.php and index1.php.

when i tried to open index.php/admin it doesn't display admin login page.
But index1.php/admin displays admin panel login page.

My questions are 
- can i manage different websites from same admin panel?
- Why admin panel for one page loads and for other it doesn't?

Comment: your website configuration is probably wrong, the secondary file should redirect to the other one.

Comment: consider both pages as home page for different websites. then it should be able to open independently.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can manage multiple websites using same admin panel. Create multiple websites from admin, everything can be managed from same admin panel

Comment: bt admin panel loads up from index1.php/admin but not from the index.php/admin. can u guess the reason behind it?